# Route different ports of same host to different instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a registered domain, let's say example.com, and 3 different services running at AWS:

1. Static web application, currently hosted at Amazon S3; port 80
2. TCP service, hosted in an EC2 instance; port 3333
3. TCP service, hosted in another EC2 instance; port 4444

All 3 services should be accessible - if possible - from the Internet by using the same hostname but different ports, i.e.

- www.example.com:80  --> S3 web app
- www.example.com:3333 ---> EC2 instance 1
- www.example.com:4444 ---> EC2 instance 2

First question is: Is this possible at all? Or should I rather use different host names like www.example.com, service1.example.com...?

If it is possible, how would it be set up and which AWS services can I use? I am still pretty new to AWS and read about (Elastic) Load Balancer, CloudFront, Route 53 but I still don't get how I could achieve my goal.

Without any further AWS service it seems to be impossible to configure a DNS entry to point to the S3 bucket, as this doesn't have a static IP address.

Any hints for a quick solution would be appreciated, as this setup is for a demo only. There won't be many users accessing the services, so from this perspective, a load balancer is not necessary and it's also not necessary for the setup to scale up at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is this possible at all?**

Answer is **Yes**.

You could have a proxy server setup to proxy the traffic according to your needs:

- Setup a DNS record for www.example.com which resolves to your proxy
  IP (Could be one of those instances you already have).
- Configure your proxy (multiple choices [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/), squid etc) to
  listen on www.example.com and the given ports and forward the traffic
  accordingly to the EC2 server IPs and the S3 website CNAME.

Is it worth it for your use case? **No** Unless you want to try it as an exercise.

**Should I rather use different host names ...?** **Yes**

Just create a hosted zone in Route53 for your domain, and create subdomains for the different services www.example.com, service1.example.com.

Comment: So, just to clarify, could I use a proxy like nginx to forward traffic to a URL/server name and NOT just an IP address (like with DNS)?

Comment: @Tobias Yes, look at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass. `The address can be specified as a domain name or IP address`

Comment: Hmm, it also states there: 'As a protocol, “http” or “https” can be specified.' I didn't read the full docs, but to me it sounds as if nginx is a proxy only for HTTP traffic and not for raw TCP? So it would be able to route to the S3 web site, but not to my TCP services. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: @Tobias you can also `proxy_pass` raw tcp using the stream proxy module: http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think you are right that the effort is not worth it for my purpose. I decided to go for the approach with different host names which is much easier (still there was lot to learn: using Route 53 and an elastic load balancer for the TCP services).
As I think your answer is the most comprehensive one, I accept it as answer for my question.

Answer (score 1):

> First question is: Is this possible at all?

Without super-complex setups, it is only possible for your TCP apps with a type of load balancers called Application Load Balancer. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html

With ALB you can create different target groups each of your TCP apps (EC2 instance 1 port 3333 and EC2 instance 2 port 4444), then define custom listeners on the load balancer to route port 3333 to the first target group and port 4444  to the second target group.

But ALB is unable to route to S3 or CloudFront distribution.

Comment: This isn't correct.  Application Load Balancer *only* supports HTTP.  For TCP, you need a classic ELB with its listeners in TCP mode, or a Network Load Balancer.